# CakePHP requestAction() alternative option w/ element

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, controller, element

I am in a situation where I am trying to pass a value from a controller action to an element directly.

The only way I know how to do this is with requestAction(), but I don't like using that feature for resource reasons and its not recommended in the manual.

Can anyone shed some light on another method?

Here is what I have now:

**Bird Controller action:**

```
    function element_array_pass() {
    $this->paginate['Bird'] = array(
        'fields'  => array('id', 'name'),
        'contain' => array('id', 'name'),
        'order'   => 'Bird.id'
    );
    $bird_elmnt = $this->paginate('Bird');
    $this->set(compact('bird_elmnt', $bird_elmnt));
}
```

**dir:** views/elements/**element_array_pass.ctp**

```
debug($bird_elmnt); // nothing being passed here.
```

**dir:** views/birds/**index.ctp**

I include the element in this file, but the array will not pass.

```
echo $this->element('element_array_pass',array("bird_elmnt" => $bird_elmnt)); // call to element.
```

I would like to include this element in my index.ctp with values passed from the action() I included above.

Comment: I believe that `paginate` is an object,  not an array. Look it up in the manual. It should show how to access it.

Comment: `paginate` is an array in the controller

Comment: I added my updated code based on my research the ideas below, but it still does not work.

Comment: and what do you mean by this? `'contain' => array('id', 'name')`

Comment: That was for Model containable, but I removed it and it makes no difference. I am thinking it might be a php setting, but I am using php5, and all my other scripts are performing as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> echo $this->element('birds_paginator_element',array('bird_elmnt_var'=>$bird_elmnt_var));
> ```

Comment: It must be something else that goes wrong. I pass data to elements all the time. Try logging the data at each step to see where you lost it.

Comment: I tested my controller vars and they contain the proper array structures and data. It's being lost at the element layer. The element does not seem to retrieve the passed value.

Comment: did you test the $bird_elmnt again right before echo the element?

Comment: Ok the variable is passed just fine, but only if it is sent from the index() action. I created a element_array_pass() action, and I am trying to pass the value that action, but using the index.ctp view. So I am trying to access the passed value from a function that is not set to the current view. Do you see what I mean? My goal with all of this was to create an independent action that returned an array which I could use for my element in any view.

Comment: @OldWest let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1686/discussion-between-anh-pham-and-oldwest)

Comment: I just wanted to not my original post indicated I was using index.ctp and I was trying to pull in the value from a different controller action. I am accepting this answer because it does work, but did not really solve my original problem avoiding the use of requestAction(). Thanks for the assistance anyhow.

Comment: well, the reason requestAction is expensive because it has to initialize another controller.
If you need the data from a particular controller across the application, you'll have to init that controller anyway, requestAction or not.
Anyway, these kinds of problem usually boil down to rethinking about your overall application design.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to pass additional data to an element through the 2nd argument of the `element()` method.

```
echo $this->element('birds_paginator_element', array(
    'bird_elmnt_var' => $bird_elmnt
));

// In element
var_dump($bird_elmnt_var);
```

Also have a read of [this](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/reducing-requestaction-use-in-your-cakephp-sites-with-fat-models) article from Mark Story.

Comment: This does not work. And I read Mark's notes as well prior to this post, and they were not effective in Cake 1.3. But thanks for the ideas.

Comment: The API for 1.3 says that it still takes a second argument as extra parameters for a element, except for the two special params which are `cache` & `plugin`: http://api.cakephp.org/class/view#method-Viewelement

Comment: Not sure but it's certainly not working that's all I know at this point. Still trying various things.